# Do class or subclass features that relate to spellcasting apply when producing a spell's effect from an Artificer's Spell-Storing Item?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, spellcasting, artificer

In [my recent question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/169351/14661) about a homebrewed Artificer subclass, I was asked in a comment how one of the abilities that modifies spellcasting would interact with casting spells stored within a my subclass's variant version of the Spell-Storing Item feature that all Artificers get. I'd not considered it before, but I suspect it should work the same as a normal spell cast from a normal Spell-Storing Item.

But as it turns out, I'm not actually sure how that works for normal Artificers either. The relevant rules text for the [Spell-Storing Item](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/artificer#Spell-StoringItem-1134246) feature says (from *Eberron: Rising from the Last War*, page 58, and the latest version of *Wayfinder's Guide to Eberron*, p. 179-180) says:

> While holding the object, a creature can take an action to produce the spell's effect from it, using your spellcasting ability modifier. If the spell requires concentration, the creature must concentrate.

Notable in that rules text is that it *does not* say that the creature using the object *casts* the spell, only that it produces the spell's effect. This seems relevant because the top voted answers to [this previous question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/50054/14661) seem to mostly attach to the "cast" terminology used by most magical items that grant extra spells.

In combination with the answers to that question, it seems like the different language (not using "cast") may mean that using a Spell-Storing Item isn't spellcasting, and so no feature that modifies spellcasting will apply. But there's enough ambiguity that I want to ask about it here.

Do an artificer's spellcasting-related features apply to spells they store in an item? Do spellcasting-related features of the creature *using* the Spell-Storing Item (which may or may not be the Artificer themself) apply?

For a concrete example, if an Artillerist stores *Scorching Ray* in a wand, staff or rod that they had previously made their Arcane Firearm, would they get an get an extra d8 to add to one of the spell's damage rolls when they use the stored spell?

Comment: Not exactly related but a similar question about word choice: "[What does the wand of wonder mean when it says “as if you had cast” vs “you cast”?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/140455)"

Comment: Related: [Does an artificer's Spell-Storing Item bypass the need for costly/consumed material components?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/174416/33569)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## The spell is never cast; "cast a spell" features don't apply

Specifically, the Artificer never casts the spell. They only choose one to store in the item. Thus any of the Artificer's features like Arcane Firearm don't apply because the Artificer doesn't cast the spell.

The user never casts the spell either. They merely use the Use an Object<sup>†</sup> action to produce the spell's effects. They don't cast it and don't get to modify it with their features which care about them casting a spell.

This is perhaps most comparable to certain potions which also bring a spells effect into being without it being cast, eg. [potion of speed](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/potion-of-speed) which apply the effects of *haste* without any creature (or other entity) casting the spell.

---

†: Clarified as such in the [Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf#page=3). Without defining it as such it would be a special, unnamed action or a Use a Magic Item action if using the definition of the Essentials Kit. Either way, it is not the Cast a Spell action.

Comment: Would "Use an Item" be the action the user takes?

Comment: @JonAristotle PHB chapter 9, Actions In Combat: *"When an object requires your action for its use, you take the Use an Object action"*, but also note DMG chapter 7, Activating An Item: *"If an item requires an action to activate, that action isn't a function of the Use an Object action, so a feature such as the rogue's Fast Hands can't be used to activate the item"*, so I think it's the DM's call whether the Spell-Storing Item uses the rules for a mundane item (yes, it's Use An Item) or a magical item (no, it's a special, unnamed action).

Comment: @anax meanwhile the *Essentials Kit* states: "If you have a magic item that requires an action to use, you take the Use a Magic Item action." Which does a clearer job than the verb choice "activate"

Comment: The [Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf#page=3) now explicitly answers the question of what kind of action is used to activate a Spell-Storing Item: "**Which action is used to activate a Spell-Storing Item?** Activating a Spell-Storing Item uses the Use an Object action." (As odd as it may seem, the Spell-Storing Item feature doesn't say it makes the object magical.)

Comment: Why would it be the Use a Magic Item action? I don't believe it states that the item becomes magic?

Comment: @Medix2 It does allow the production of a spell's effect which the SAC includes in the "is magical" test, though I'm not sure that applies to the produced spell effect or the item producing it. You could store the spell in an object that is magical (for other reasons) and that would change the action? I suppose I could just take out the reference to the Essentials kit, and just stick with the normal rules sources.

Comment: @Someone Oh gosh, that's a fun one (the action changing based on the item used). It's a good thing the action type doesn't matter for anything besides the Thief Rogue's Fast Hands, I think...

Comment: One thing that you might want to mention is that this is different from most magic items that cast spells -- most magic items say "You can cast the X spell" or "Use N chanrges to cast X spell" which do allow you to use to use most class features for spell casting (like meta magic) on the spell -- but spell storing is storing the effect that was previously cast.