# Does the Artificer's Spell-Storing Item effectively bypass the bonus action spellcasting rule?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, spellcasting, artificer, bonus-action

The rule on [Bonus Action Casting Time](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#BonusAction) states:

> A spell cast with a bonus action is especially swift. You must use a bonus action on your turn to cast the spell, provided that you haven't already taken a bonus action this turn. You can't cast another spell during the same turn, except for a cantrip with a casting time of 1 action.

This would ordinarily prevent you from casting a levelled spell and a bonus action spell on the same turn; however, the Artificer's Spell-Storing Item states:

> [...] While holding the object, a creature can take an action to produce the spell's effect from it, using your spellcasting ability modifier. [...]

Furthermore, the following question's highest-scoring answer states:

- [Do class or subclass features that relate to spellcasting apply when producing a spell's effect from an Artificer's Spell-Storing Item?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/169477)

> [...] The user never casts the spell either. They merely use a (special, unnamed) action to produce the spell's effects. They don't cast it and don't get to modify it with their features which care about them casting a spell. [...]

And the [Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf) even states (page 3):

> Q. Which action is used to activate a Spell-Storing Item?
>
> A. Activating a Spell-Storing Item uses the Use an Object action.

Does this mean that a caster could use a Spell-Storing Item, creating the effects of any 1st or 2nd level Artificer spell with a casting time of 1 action, and then use their bonus action to cast any (bonus action) spell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Yes, this works: the "Bonus Action Casting" rule only applies when you cast a spell using your bonus action.

Spell Storing Item states:

> While holding the object, a creature can take an action to produce the spell’s effect from it, using your spellcasting ability modifier.

There are two important observations we must make about this feature:

- You are not casting the spell
- You are using your Action, not your Bonus Action

With these things in mind, consider the bonus action casting rule:

> A spell cast with a bonus action is especially swift. You must use a bonus action on your turn to cast the spell, provided that you haven't already taken a bonus action this turn. You can't cast another spell during the same turn, except for a cantrip with a casting time of 1 action.

There two important observations we must make about this rule. It applies when each of the following is true:

- You are casting a spell,
- That spell has a casting time of 1 Bonus Action

Since Spell Storing Item does not involve casting a spell with your Bonus Action, the bonus action casting rule does not apply.

Answer (score 3):

#### Yes, you can.

Casting a spell as your bonus action prevents you from casting a spell with your Action unless it's a Cantrip. You are, however, free to use your Action to activate a magic item, unless that magic item specifies that it is casting a spell. The magic items produced by the Spell-Storing Item class feature don't state that they allow you to cast a spell, simply "producing the spell's effect" of the spell stored within them, so you're free to use them in conjunction with casting a Bonus Action spell.