# Can you Invoke a Rune during a Rage?

Tags: dnd-5e, multi-classing, barbarian, rage, rune-knight

Can a Barbarian/Fighter (Rune Knight) multiclasser invoke a rune (for example the Fire Rune) while raging?

I don't see anything to suggest otherwise, since invoking a rune is not casting a spell and does not require concentration. Is there any reason they would not work together?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### The only thing you can't do while raging is cast or concentrate on spells

The Barbarian's Rage feature states:

> [...] If you are able to cast spells, you can’t cast them or concentrate on them while raging. [...]

This is the only sort of restriction the feature applies on anything magical. The runes do *not* involve casting spells, if they did, they would explicitly state as much like the Way of Four Elements Monk does with its Fist of Four Thunders feature (and many others):

> [...] Some elemental disciplines allow you to cast spells. [...]
>
> [...] You can spend 2 ki points to cast *thunderwave*. [...]

This feature explicitly states that you cast a spell, and since the Rune Knight's Runes do *not* include a similar wording, they are not considered to be casting a spell and thus a Barbarian can use them while raging. There is [a somewhat similar case with an Artificer's Spell-Storing Item](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/169478) where since it does not explicitly state that you are casting the spell, you are not actually casting it.